# How to validate google recaptcha on client side?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, recaptcha, login-control

I have implemented google reCaptcha on a login panel showing after 3 unsuccessful login

But I want to validate reCaptcha on a client slide using jQuery on clicking of login button here is the code

```
<div style="display:none;width:310px;top:205px;left:558px;position:absolute" id="grecaptcha" runat="server">
  <cc1:GoogleReCaptcha  ID="ctrlGoogleReCaptcha1"  runat="server" PublicKey="6LdHrQ0TAAAAAD77ubv9Jr6q4RYkyddhXzX-XPB3" PrivateKey="xxxxxxx" />

  </div>
  <span id="captcha" style="margin-left:588px;color:red" />
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="get_action();" CommandName="Login" Text="Inloggen" ValidationGroup="Login1" />
```

How can I do this by using jQuery?

Comment: Never share your credentials publicly at least not the private key which are provide by API's.

Comment: Have a look at this link [Recaptcha Validation From Client](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Validate-Google-RECaptcha-on-Client-Side-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery-in-ASPNet.aspx) it will give you a rough idea how to implement one and kindly visit recaptcha page and generate a new creadential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I share my code solution. But the *proxy.php* and other details with the full explanation (incl. backend part) you might find **[here](http://scraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/)**.

### Recaptcha with *data-callback* parameter

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" >;
<form method="post">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[site_key]" data-callback="onReturnCallback" data-theme="light"></div>
<input value="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

### JS validation

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var onReturnCallback = function(response) { 
    //alert('g-recaptcha-response: ' + grecaptcha.getResponse()); 
    var url='proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';  
    $.ajax({ 'url' : url, 
               dataType: 'json',
               data: { response: response},
               success: function( data  ) {                     
                var res = data.success.toString();
                        alert( "User verified: " + res);                    
                if (res ==  'true') { 
                       document.getElementById('g-recaptcha').innerHTML = 'THE CAPTCHA WAS SUCCESSFULLY SOLVED'; 
                                } 
                           } // end of success: 
         }); // end of $.ajax 
}; // end of onReturnCallback 
</script>
```

### Note!

The backend part, **proxy.php**, is necessary because of security issue.

Comment: Where is the secret key in here ? You are calling the API wrong. it won't work.

Comment: @ShaikhShahid, secret key **is not to be exposed on client-side**. See the *proxy.php* [here](http://scraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/).

Comment: So you are having a backend ? Title is confusing.

Comment: @ShaikhShahid, backend *is necessary because of security issue*. Sorry if the title made you confused.