# Complete a reCAPTCHA form to make a phone-call

Tags: html, web, recaptcha, conventions, smartphone

I'd like people to contact me from my personal page (which is mobile and desktop friendly), but I don't want my cell phone number scraped by bots. So I thought I could have users visiting my page check off the Google reCAPTCHA form to get access to my phone number.

```
<form action="?" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc5XQ4TAAAAAN18KgCH-E-tVEVnzwP80NDX9v9Q"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So what do I do put for the form action? I don't want my number there using the "tel:" standard because then my number is still visible in the source code.

In summary, I'm just wondering what's the best way to programmatically instantiate a phone call without revealing the phone number or allowing bots to scrape.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot use reCaptcha on client-side only.

You need a server-side language (just) to process and validate captcha requests.

Like PHP, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You put the URL of a server side program which reads `g-recaptcha-response` from the submitted form data and verifies it as [described in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) and then outputs either an error message or an HTML document containing your contact details.

Comment: Oh right, I didn't read that step! So it looks like Google has a page where you send your `g-recaptcha-response`: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify. It looks like it returns a JSON response with a boolean field **success**. So how do I take the response and start a phone call?

Comment: The safe option is, as mentioned, to output an HTML document containing your contact details. `<a href="tel:your number">your number</a>` is a good bet. If you want to assume (and you know what they say about assumptions) that the user's browser has a tel scheme URI handler set up correct then you could output an HTTP redirect to the tel scheme URI.

Comment: Gotcha! Perhaps it's best if I just leave the phone number as a HTML link. So then the question is, if I include the reCAPTCHA as:
`<form action="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" method="POST">
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Lc5XQ4TAAAAAN18KgCH-E-tVEVnzwP80NDX9v9Q"></div>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>`
How do I save the results of Google's siteverify endpoint? Do I need some other Javascript to capture the result and replace the reCAPTCHA with the phone-number link?

Comment: You don't do that. `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` is the URL of the webservice that your server side program talks to. The form submits to your server side program on  your site.

Answer (score 0):

> ...if I include the reCAPTCHA form... How do I save the results of Google's siteverify endpoint? Do I need some other Javascript to capture the result and replace the reCAPTCHA with the phone-number link?

Sure you need some Javascript browser based logic to verify real human against bot. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32966339/1230477) and the complete [post](http://scraping.pro/insert-configure-recaptcha-no-captcha-code-in-php/).

In my answer the ajax call to thre proxy.php makes user to verify. 
So if it's successful you make an another ajax call to your server to retrieve your phone number and insert it instead of *g-recaptcha* code. Thus you keep privacy by setting your phone number to only those who's proved being human:

```
...
var url='proxy.php?url=' + 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$.ajax({ 'url' : url, 
           dataType: 'json',
           data: { response: response},
           success: function( data  ) {                     
            var res = data.success.toString();
                    // alert( "User verified: " + res);                    
            if (res ==  'true') { 
                    $.ajax( url: '<url to fetch your phone number>',
                            success: function( phone ){
                              document.getElementById('g-recaptcha').innerHTML = phone;
                            } // end of success for phone
                    ); // end of $.ajax to get phone

             } // end if
          } // end of success for user verify 
     }); // end of $.ajax to proxy.php
```